# How do I get a discord bot to send a random message inside an embed in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, embed

So I wanted to use a command that puts a random message inside of an embed that also has a random gif attached to it, here is the code I'm using:

```
roastgifs = [
'https://tenor.com/view/roasted-oh-shookt-gif-8269968'
]


@client.command(aliases=['Roast']) 
async def roast(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    global roasting
    global sus
    
    roasting = [line.strip() for line in open('jokes.txt')]
    sus = random.choice(roasting)
    
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.mention} roasts {member.mention}\n\"" + sus + "\"")
    roastgif=random.choice(roastgifs)
    embed.set_image(url=roastgif)
    embed.set_footer("footer")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I can't find that many tutorials on yt and Google and even then they're probably js and not py so I resorted to coming here again.

Also I would greatly appreciate how to make the bot ping someone with an ID if that's alright.

Comment: What's exactly happening? What's wrong with the code? What's the current result? What's the expected result? Any errors/tracebacks?

Comment: What's happening is I'm trying to open a separate file with strings of text and using "random.choice" to make it send a random string of text, then I make an embed, use an f string to make use for {ctx.author.mention} and {member.mention} and adding one string of text to the Sus variable that stores the random choice thing, then use a variable to get a random choice of one of the GIFs stored in the roastgifs area, then use a footer then use ctx.send to send it but it won't send anything when I use the command, no errors or anything but it won't send anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Embed.set_footer` takes only keyword arguments, and you're passing a positional argument

```py
embed.set_footer(text="Footer")
```

Also a few things:

1. You cannot ping in the embed title/footer (and somewhere else too, don't remember where atm)
2. The gif won't load. You only can add pictures in `Embed.set_image`

#### Reference:

- [`Embed.set_footer`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=set_footer#discord.Embed.set_footer)
- [`Embed.set_image`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=set_footer#discord.Embed.set_image)